# How to call table from another HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I am working in zoho. There are 2 pages I have created namely `test` and `test2`. I need to access `table` which is present in the `test2` page from `test page`. I guess, I need to call that `table` by some name. Is there any mechanism by which I can access that `test2 table` from `test` page.

Comment: Possibly Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993243/how-to-call-another-table-in-the-same-page

Comment: You can use ajax simply to that page get the table contents and append in your page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `LocalStorage` (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) in javascript. What you would do is serialize your test2 form's data (e.g. using JSON), and store that into `LocalStorage` which your other window, test, will also be able to access.

For example, in test2 you would have something like this:

```
var tableHTML = document.getElementById("yourTableID").innerHTML;
window.localStorage["sharedTable"] = tableHTML;
```

And in `test` you would have:

```
var tableHTML = window.localStorage["sharedTable"];
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.innerHTML = tableHTML;
//now table will be just like what you would get in test2 window if you did document.getElementById('yourTableId');
```

Here is kind of a unique situation for a demo... I have two JSFiddles which represent your two windows / pages. Open the first link first because that represents test2 which must run first in order to be accessible. Then open the 2nd and see the table HTML from the other page be alerted.

Open first (Page2):
http://jsfiddle.net/mLy4tje2/

Open second: (Page1);
http://jsfiddle.net/qx2xodns/

Comment: Do be aware that this won't be compatible with older browsers - meant to put that in the answer.

Comment: check out a quick demo

Answer (score 0):

You may create a table as a separate html page, and display it in test and test2 using `iframe` tags.

[iframe Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

It is not a permanent solution. It's a idea to share a html between two pages.